# How to sum date based dictionary values in python?

Tags: python

I have the below dictionary format, I want to sum the dictionary values based on date.

```
dict1 = [
            {'date':"10-05-2017", 'cost':20},
            {'date':"10-05-2017", 'cost':10},
            {'date':"11-05-2017", 'cost':15},
            {'date':"11-05-2017", 'cost':10},
            {'date':"12-05-2017", 'cost':5}
        ]
```

Result:

```
[
    {'date':"10-05-2017", 'cost':30},
    {'date':"11-05-2017", 'cost':25},
    {'date':"12-05-2017", 'cost':5}
]
```

Comment: Fantastic. Can you please show your code for this and indicate what difficulties you are facing in your own implementation?

Comment: The fact that the string value represents a date isn't really relevant here.

Comment: pandas might be useful here, if you're comfortable with it

Comment: I will get the list of bill amounts here. I want to sum the bill amount based on date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> [{"date": key, "cost": sum(d["cost"] for d in group)} 
...  for key, group in itertools.groupby(dict1, key=lambda d: d["date"])]
[{'cost': 30, 'date': '10-05-2017'},
 {'cost': 25, 'date': '11-05-2017'},
 {'cost': 5, 'date': '12-05-2017'}]
```

Note that this only works if dictionaries with the same date are adjacent to each other, i.e. if unsure, best sort the list by the same `key` first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = {}
for i in dict1:
    result[i['date']] = result.setdefault(i["date"], 0) + i["cost"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
dict1 = [
        {'date':"10-05-2017", 'cost':20},
        {'date':"10-05-2017", 'cost':10},
        {'date':"11-05-2017", 'cost':15},
        {'date':"11-05-2017", 'cost':10},
        {'date':"12-05-2017", 'cost':5}
    ]
new_data = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby([i.items() for i in dict1], key=lambda x:list(x)[0][1])]
final_dict = [{"date":a, "cost":sum(list(i)[-1][-1] for i in b if "cost" in list(i)[-1])} for a, b in new_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'date': '10-05-2017', 'cost': 30}, {'date': '11-05-2017', 'cost': 25}, {'date': '12-05-2017', 'cost': 5}]
```

Comment: What's with the dict-to-list-conversion? This is not only highly un-intuitive but also relies on the iteration order of the keys in the dict, which depends on the type of dict, and maybe even on the Python implementation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your records by date.

This function needs a *key*: another function used to extract the date. You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) for that.

Here is a short solution using this features and a comprehension list:

```
import itertools
import operator


dict1 = [{'cost': 20, 'date': '10-05-2017'},
         {'cost': 10, 'date': '10-05-2017'},
         {'cost': 15, 'date': '11-05-2017'},
         {'cost': 10, 'date': '11-05-2017'},
         {'cost': 5,  'date': '12-05-2017'}]

get_date = operator.itemgetter('date')
get_cost = operator.itemgetter('cost')

result = [{'date': date, 'cost': sum(map(get_cost, group))}
          for date, group in itertools.groupby(dict1, key=get_date)]
```

**note:** the *dict1* (which is a list of dictionaries) should be sorted by date:

```
dict1.sort(key=get_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `dict1` is not a dictionary, it is a list of dictionaries. Try the following script only using the standar library.

```
from collections import Counter

dict1 = [
    {'date':"10-05-2017", 'cost':20},
    {'date':"10-05-2017", 'cost':10},
    {'date':"11-05-2017", 'cost':15},
    {'date':"11-05-2017", 'cost':10},
    {'date':"12-05-2017", 'cost':5}
]

counter = Counter()

for each in dict1:
    counter.update({each['date']: each['cost']})

[{'date': key, 'cost': value} for key, value in counter.items()]
```