# Sum values from dictionary with same date

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I'm kind of stuck in a problem. I have a dictionary with different items in it. Each item is has 4 keys and values and I'm only interested in two of them.

```
"data": [
    {
      "count_date": "2018/12/06",
      "time_gap": 51,
      "count": 2,
      "average_speed": 20
    },
    {
      "count_date": "2018/12/06",
      "time_gap": 52,
      "count": 3,
      "average_speed": 27
    },
    {
      "count_date": "2018/12/06",
      "time_gap": 53,
      "count": 3,
      "average_speed": 17
    },
    {
      "count_date": "2018/12/06",
      "time_gap": 54,
      "count": 2,
      "average_speed": 24
    },
...
```

I would like, for each "count_date" to be able to sum the "count".

I've tried for loops to be able to get the "count_date" as a variable and check if it changes but I don't see how to properly do it (besides, this would also be in another nested for loop which I feel would be heavy to process).
I've also read this question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770171/how-to-sum-date-based-dictionary-values-in-python) on stackoverflow mentioning itertools.groupby but I don't really get how it works and how I could apply it to my case.

The end goal is here to generate an Excel file from a panda df with the sum of each count for each day.

I would also like to find the most efficient way to process it as I'm getting my data from an API and am afraid to get a timeout.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: Use a dictionary where `count_date` is the key, and the sum of `count` is the valiue.

Comment: If this will end up in a pandas dataframe anyways, why not just read the data with [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) ?